Looking for a book regarding outlier/anomaly detection in time series using confidence or prediction interval
I read a book/paper long time ago where the author describes how to use model and its confidence/prediction interval to detect outliers and replace them with the forecasting value.
It had a nice time series plot demonstrating this and if I recall correctly then the interval was in brownish colour.
If I can recall then the book chapter was about how to replace outliers with difference values by detecting them using the interval.
I have now been search for this book chapter/article for past years but not close finding it again. So, I am hoping if someone can pin point this and give me the name of the book/article.
Thanks in advance!
